# DSolve[] and initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

Take some simple function of 2 variables, e.g. f[x_,y_] := x+y and try to solve a PDE of it for the general solution:

```
DSolve[{Derivative[1,0][f][x,y] == 1, Derivative[0,1][f][x,y] == 1},f,{x,y}]
```

This works as expected. However, if you try to give an initial condition for a particular solution, MMA is no more able to solve it:

```
DSolve[{Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] == 1, 
  Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] == 1, f[0, 0] == 0}, f, {x, y}]
```

Has anyone an explanation?

Comment: Because your boundary condition contradicts the first equation?

Comment: Yes you are right, than you. Initially I had the problem with an initial condition, where it still pops up. When I wrote the question I formulated it, without much thinking, to a boundary condition.  I changed the question now, using the initial condition.